# Checkbox validation not working

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have some javascript that is supposed to validate a checkbox (making it mandatory) but my form regardless of whether it is checked or not just submits, here is my code :

```
<script>
  function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    if (!theForm.declare.checked) {
      alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
      return false;
    } else {    
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes(this);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Any ideas on why it isnt working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) 
{
if (!theForm.declare.checked)
{
    alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
    return false;
} else {    
    return true;
}
}
</script>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes(this);">

<input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare">

</form>
```

As @shin mentioned, you need to specify the object of the form during the function call.
`theForm.declare.checked` returns `true` or `false` there is no need to check the value with `==` operator. Just use it directly (User **!** depending on need - to negate the result)

Comment: I have found out why the answers i am getting aren't working, i have edited my initial post and was wondering if you could explain to me why the clashing codes caused this problem? I have also used your code which is now working.

Answer (score 0):

change your function call like

```
         return validateCheckBoxes(this);
```

**Eg:**

```
      <form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes(this);">
```

Because theForm should refer an object

Comment: I have found out why the answers i am getting aren't working, i have edited my initial post and was wondering if you could explain to me why the clashing codes caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
  function validateCheckBoxes() 
  {
    if (document.getElementById('declare').checked == false)
     {
      alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
      return false;
     } else {    
     return true;
     }
  }
</script>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi"        onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes();">

<input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a what I tried and worked for me

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function validateCheckBoxes() 
{
if (document.forms[0].declare.checked == false)
{
    alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
    return false;
} else {    
    return true;
}
}
</script>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="yourURL/search" id="eoi"  onsubmit="return validateCheckBoxes();">
    <input type="checkbox" name="declare" id="declare"/>
</form>
```

I don't think you need to pass the reference of the form object to the function.

Comment: it seems like the code below my HTML is preventing my checkbox validation from working because when i put the code below my HTML between /* */ (making it inactive) the checkbox validation code works fine